# How can I use heat.exe to include a constantly changing directory-tree?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dynamic, directory, wix, heat

so I have successfully used the WiX extension `heat.exe` to create static fragment of my directory tree I want to install using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTctUffErjs) (which is really great by the way!)...

but since its a huge project and there are constant changes being made as I write... it doesn't help much to have a static fragment which you would have to edit and include into the `.wxs` each time a change is made... I have searched the web yet not found anything useful on this matter... only the hint that using `HeatDirectory Task` and/or `HeatDirectory Target` could lead to a solution?

Is there anybody that has some more knowledge in this matter or has already solved a similar problem? I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Which way would you like to go [Visual Studio/MSBuild](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/target_reference/harvestdirectory.html) or stick with command-line tools directly?

Comment: hm...whats the difference? or in other words what do you mean by using the cmd-tools?

As for the link: Would using the `HarvestDirectory Target` force me to put in each of the sub-directory paths for @HarvestDirectory? I hope not...^^

would you maybe happen to have an example for how to use `HarvestDirectory Target` correctly?

Answer (score 0):

We have a WiX project in Visual Studio and we use a pre build step to create our .wxs files.

It creates a temp folder, copies all the files that we would like to have (in this case the result of a Publish action) and then calls heat with this directory and some other info as parameters.

```
call rd /s /q "$(ProjectDir)gatheredSetupFilesDir"
call md "$(ProjectDir)gatheredSetupFilesDir"

call xcopy "$(SolutionDir)..\ProjectDir\Published\*" "$(ProjectDir)gatheredSetupFilesDir" /S /Y

call "$(WIX)bin\heat.exe" dir "$(ProjectDir)gatheredSetupFilesDir" -cg ProjectComponents -dr INSTALLFOLDER -ag -srd -sfrag -scom -suid  -sreg -var var.gatheredSetupFilesDir -out "$(ProjectDir)Includes\ProjectComponents.wxs"
```

Comment: in this process of copying the temp .wxs file and running it with heat ....do you the still have the possibility to add some custom changes automatically? or would you have to do those manually each time a new temp file is generated??

Comment: In this example every change you make, post-generation, would be lost the next time the build is made as it's generated again each time. What "custom changes" are you talking about?